# Retrofit and gson Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, api, gson, retrofit2

Im using retrofit 2.4.0 and gson 2.8.5 , i got this exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

I have searched so many similar question , no one gives me solution .any one please help me to solve this error.

gradle :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Server response is :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "result": 1,
    "message": "Profile successfully updated"
}
```

ResponseModel :

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResponseModel {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Integer result;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

 public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

 public Integer getResult() {
    return result;
 }

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
 }
}
```

ApiInterface :

```
public interface ApiInterface {

   public static final String BASE_URL ='..';

    @Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
        "Accept: application/json"})
    @Multipart
    @POST("/profile/update")
    Call<ResponseModel> uploadImage(@Header("X-Header") String defaultHeader,
                                @Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                                @Part("gender") RequestBody gender);


   public class ApiClient {
        public static ApiInterface apiInterface;
        public static ApiInterface getApiInterface() {
            if (apiInterface == null) {

               Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();

                apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
                return apiInterface;
            } else {
                return apiInterface;
            }
        }
 }
```

in MainActivity.java

```
 File file = new File(ImagePath);
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);
            RequestBody ReqBodyName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), nameValue);
            RequestBody ReqBodyGender = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), genderValue);

ApiInterface.ApiClient.getApiInterface().uploadImage(DEFAULT_HEADER,AUTH_HEADER,fileToUpload,ReqBodyName,ReqBodyGender).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseModel> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseModel> response) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "resp"+new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    Log.d("Log",response.raw().toString());
                    Log.d("Log Status",response.body().getStatus());
                    Log.d("Log Message",response.body().getMessage());


                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response"+response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("Error====",t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error :"+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: post the onResponse and onfaliure

Comment: ok , wait i will updating question

Comment: @ AL Tegani , please check updated question

Comment: show which responce log print

Comment: no im getting error from android app

Comment: Hi @SaurabhMistry, can you double check if the response is correct by using cUrl or postman

Comment: yes i have multiple time checked response from server

Comment: try using `Call<ResponseBody>` instead of `Call<ResponseModel>`, also replace all references

Answer (score 0):

gson converter error it except the class object it gives the string.

```
Gson converter convert the json response to java object 
and java object to the json respectively
```

Create the proper pojo according to the response refer this site for making pojo : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/